# How to use Minio as frontend to BindFS mount

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, ubuntu-16.04, fuse, minio

### Introduction

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and trying to run a Minio instance with a bucket whose contents are exposed via a BindFS mount.  My backend directory structure looks like the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ll minio_test_dir/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 33 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:01 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:02 backend/
drwx------  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:02 .minio-test/
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:02 minio-test-storage/
```

where `backend` represents my remote storage and is just a normal directory:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ll minio_test_dir/backend/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:02 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct  7 14:02 ../
```

I'm starting Minio using the following command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/minio_test_dir$ ~/minio -C ./.minio-test server --address ":9002" minio-test-storage

Endpoint:  http://192.168.0.107:9002  http://127.0.0.1:9002  http://10.0.3.1:9002
AccessKey: 9DSOXCX63U3CGOJ3LWO3 
SecretKey: pEGNthXl5sQLz2L10dX63bBNBMB2SXSpd4CDj44A 
Region:    us-east-1
SqsARNs: 

Browser Access:
   http://192.168.0.107:9002  http://127.0.0.1:9002  http://10.0.3.1:9002

Command-line Access: https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide
   $ mc config host add myminio http://192.168.0.107:9002 9DSOXCX63U3CGOJ3LWO3 pEGNthXl5sQLz2L10dX63bBNBMB2SXSpd4CDj44A

Object API (Amazon S3 compatible):
   Go:         https://docs.minio.io/docs/golang-client-quickstart-guide
   Java:       https://docs.minio.io/docs/java-client-quickstart-guide
   Python:     https://docs.minio.io/docs/python-client-quickstart-guide
   JavaScript: https://docs.minio.io/docs/javascript-client-quickstart-guide
```

I can now quite happy visit the Minio browser at http://192.168.0.107:9002, log in using the provided credentials, create a bucket, and upload files:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/minio_test_dir$ tree minio-test-storage/
minio-test-storage/
└── test.bucket
    ├── aaa.txt
    └── bbb.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

if I use BindFS to join my Minio bucket to my backend storage, thusly:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/minio_test_dir$ bindfs backend/ minio-test-storage/test.bucket/
```

the command succeeds, and I can see in `/proc/mounts`:

```
bindfs /home/ubuntu/minio_test_dir/minio-test-storage/test.bucket fuse.bindfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

Note that in `/etc/fuse.conf`, I have `user_allow_other` uncommented.

### The Problem

Once BindFS has been mounted, I can no longer upload files through the Minio browser.  Opening the Javascript console, I see the following error:

```
PUT http://192.168.0.107:9002/minio/upload/test.bucket/test-upload.txt 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

with the following response received in the Network tab:

```
We encountered an internal error, please try again.
```

I am really at a loss for how to diagnose this.  If I try to manually create a file, e.g. via `touch` or `echo >` then this works as expected.  I have looked far and wide to try and figure out how to see logs from Minio and have come up empty.  I note that my `.minio-test` directory contains a `config.json` file with the following promising-seeming snippet:

```
"logger": {
            "console": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "level": "fatal"
            },
            "file": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "fileName": "",
                    "level": ""
            },
            "syslog": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "address": "",
                    "level": ""
            }
    }
```

but I have been unable to get any of these options to actually output any logs, as far as I can tell.  I did find [this bug report](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/1419) which claims to have been fixed, but the issue seems to remain.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`minio-test-storage` and `test.bucket` should be of the on the same FS device, when you use bindfs the device number of the FS of `test.bucket` changes because of which operations like `rename` of files from the `minio-test-storage` FS to `test.bucket` FS fails.

what you can do is:
`ln -s backend minio-test-storage/test.bucket`

This creates `test.bucket` as a symlink to `backend` directory which  creates the desired effect for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'll be able to try this on Monday morning, I'll report back then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately for my purposes I need to be able to use BindFS.  I tried a setup where I link `backend` to a new `backend-dummy` directory via BindFS, and then join `backend-dummy` to `minio-test-storage/test.bucket` via `ln -s backend minio-test-storage/test.bucket` as you suggest.  Unfortunately I received the same error message as before.  I've run a quick test using s3rver instead of Minio and my use case appears to work just fine without needing to use a symlink.

Comment: OK, the export directory and bucket directory should be on same device for minio to work. What happens is there is a dir called `.minio.sys` inside which uploaded objects are put temporarily before renaming it to the actual location. This rename fails if the `.minio.sys` is on a different device than the `bucket` directory.

Comment: Yeah I've played around with this some more and realised that that's the case.  Is there any way to work around this?  I know that in Linux the `mv` command falls back to doing a copy/remove if the rename fails, which explains why I'm able to manually move things between `.minio.sys/tmp` and `test.bucket`.  Am I out of luck here?

Comment: @RobGwynn-Jones you can open an issue at [here](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/new) giving this SO link as reference, but mostly nothing can be done about it. But if you can explain in the issue what you are trying to achieve maybe we can find a work around.